# How to hide footer on customized rails 404 page in liquid shopify template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, liquid

I am working on a rails website with views made predominantly with liquid shopify. I customized the default rails 404 error message to something more dynamic that would display an animation and the top menu of the website. My new error pages are named not_found.html.erb and internal_server_error.html.erb. Aside the top menu that displays automatically on the new error page, the footer displays as well and i want to take it out. The top menu and the footer are liquid templates. I want to take out the liquid footer on only the two error pages i mentioned above.

Comment: Works for me! ;)

Comment: No, but seriously, you *need* to **show us some code**. I can't magically fix the problem without seeing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the erb templates to liquid. Then i put this as the first line in the views that i changed from erb to liquid.

```
<style>
   footer { display:none; }
</style>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on Shopify template with liquid code. you can use:

```
{% unless template contains '404' %}
{% include 'footer' %}
{% endunless %}
```